# ConfigurationSection alternatives (.NET 4.5.1)

Tags: c#, configuration-files

Is there a better and cleaner way to create configuration files as opposed to using ConfigurationSection?
Below is code that is very error prone to typing the names wrong as well as messy and ugly code. now normally this might be okay if u have few configurations, but I have over a 100 and maintaining this code becomes a nightmare and very ugly..

Below is the code i currently have.

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("gridPageSize", DefaultValue = 10)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 100)]
    public int GridPageSize
    {
        get { return (int)this["gridPageSize"]; }
        set { this["gridPageSize"] = value; }
    }
```

**UPDATED**
At the very least I would like to read the "gridPageSize" string from a resourcefile, while this works for get;set, it does not work for the ConfigurationPropertyAttribute

Comment: I always use constants for this sort of thing.  Still have to update in a few places (xml, .cs) but a lot fewer copies of the string everywhere.

Comment: Project + Properties, Settings.  Probably too late for that.

Comment: MSFT should look into this. I've been calling out for a better way to do configuration for a long time. This kind of thing should be completely declarative, and of course much less complex than what MSFT provides.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [West Wind Application Configuration for .NET](https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.ApplicationConfiguration). Rick's design is cleaner and still flexible.

Even for Microsoft, the old configuration design is too complex. Its IIS team uses XML schema files to replace such hardcoded sections for IIS 7 and above, which is an alternative way. However, that piece of code is not open sourced sadly.